# retrieve directory using just part of file name vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I ant to retrieve the directory of a notepad txt file but I have only just part of the filename of the notepad? Is it possible to do so , any quick way? I am using vb 2010 express for your information

Comment: What part of the filename do you have and what have you tried so far?

Comment: I found this MSDN entry for [Directory.GetFiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316(v=vs.110).aspx) which sounds like it is what you are looking for. You can enter your search term and the search option `IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories`.

Answer (score 0):

```
''' <summary>
''' Gets all dirctories containing the file which its part is specified.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="PartOfTXT">The file specified. Do not contain the TXT extension.</param>
''' <returns>All dirctories containing the file which its part is specified.</returns>
''' <remarks>Comment if anything is wrong.</remarks>
Function GetTXTDirectory(PartOfTXT As String) As String()
    Dim List As New System.Collections.Generic.List(Of String)
    For Each Drive As System.IO.DriveInfo In System.IO.DriveInfo.GetDrives
        List.AddRange(System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(
            Drive.Name, "*"c & PartOfTXT & "*.txt", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    Next
    Return List.ToArray
End Function
```